# How to find a polynom so that $\hat{P}=P(\phi)=\phi^{-1}?$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

We consider an automorphism (bijective endomorphism) $\phi$ of a finite-dimensional vector space $V$. The aim is to show that it exists a polynom $P$ such as the endomorphism linked to this polynom $\hat{P}=P(\phi)=\phi^{-1}$.

I really don’t know how to begin the exercise. I tried to consider a random polynom $\sum\limits_{j=1}^k\alpha_i x^i$, but no conclusion could been found. Could you please give me a hint?

Comment: a random polynomial? Why not to try the most natural polynomial associated to a matrix? Cayley-Hamilton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mu$ be the minimal polynomial of $\phi$. By hypothesis, the gcd of $\mu$ and $x$ is equal to $1$: otherwise, $x$ would divide $\mu(x)$, in contradiction with the fact that $\phi$ is invertible. According to [Bézout’s identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity?wprov=sfti1) for polynomials, it exist polynomials $p,q$ such that

$$p(x)\mu(x)+q(x) x= 1.$$ Replacing $x$ with $\phi$, we get

$$q(\phi)\phi= p(\phi)\mu(\phi) +q(\phi)\phi =Id.$$
We finally get the desired conclusion
$$\phi^{-1}=q(\phi).$$

Comment: Is there any other possibility if we don’t know the Bézout´s identity? For example with the minimal polynom…

Comment: @Tomleboss Yes, you have at least to notice that $x$ can’t divide the minimal polynomial. Then it is easy to prove the desired result.